# AutoHotKey stopped working after plugging new keyboard, even if I restart computer

Tags: autohotkey

I upgraded my keyboard. Problem is that now all the scripts stopped working. Even simple scripts from the tutorials don't work.

This happens in all applications, and ever if I plug in my old keyboard and restart the computer, autohotkey just does not work any more even in my previous configuration. I've tried also running in administrator mode.

What I do see however is the following, that the script works only once each time autohotkey is relaunced. For example:

```
^j::
Send, My First Script
Return
```

This works the first time ctrl-j is pressed, however afterwards it does not work again until I restart autohotkey.

Any ideas? I have Windows 10 x64, 1.1.23.05. I did not install any new drivers with the new keyboard (it's a standard usb keyboard, though a mechanical type).

Here are some more examples of simple scripts that don't work:

```
SetCapslockState AlwaysOff
```

In this case the first time I press the capslock, it's indeed ignored, but all the next times I click it works normally.

```
a::return
```

Again, same behaviour: a is ignored the first time, but next time it works normally, until I restart AHK (and again then it works only the first time).

Note that in all cases I'm running AHK only with the single line scripts you see; nothing else.

Below is the Key History and last lines when pressing Ctrl-J (of the first example)

```
Window: C:\Files\Tools\AutoHotKey\1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.23.05
Keybd hook: yes
Mouse hook: no
Enabled Timers: 0 of 0 ()
Interrupted threads: 0
Paused threads: 0 of 0 (0 layers)
Modifiers (GetKeyState() now) = 
Modifiers (Hook's Logical) = 
Modifiers (Hook's Physical) = 
Prefix key is down: no

NOTE: To disable the key history shown below, add the line "#KeyHistory 0" anywhere in the script.  The same method can be used to change the size of the history buffer.  For example: #KeyHistory 100  (Default is 40, Max is 500)

The oldest are listed first.  VK=Virtual Key, SC=Scan Code, Elapsed=Seconds since the previous event.  Types: h=Hook Hotkey, s=Suppressed (blocked), i=Ignored because it was generated by an AHK script, a=Artificial, #=Disabled via #IfWinActive/Exist, U=Unicode character (SendInput).

VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
74  03F     d   11.94   F5              C:\Files\Tools\AutoHotKey\1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.23.05
A2  01D     d   3.09    LControl        *c:\Files\Tools\AutoHotKey\1.ahk - Notepad++
74  03F     d   1.99    F5              C:\Files\Tools\AutoHotKey\1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.23.05
Press [F5] to refresh.
```

Lines

```
001: Return (15.77)
003: if ( GetKeyState( "Control" , "P" ) )  
007: Return (150.50)
```

Comment: Do you release Ctrl key afterwards? (You have to release it.)

Comment: Yes I release the key. The script above is just an example of something trivial that stopped working. I scaled down my more complex script in case something there was the problem, but even simple scripts don't work.